# MySQL implementation rejects 'now()' in quotes

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a server which won't allow

UPDATE some-table SET last_modified = 'now()' where row_id = 1;

but does allow

UPDATE some-table SET last_modified = now() where row_id = 1;

What setting is it that causes this to fail? I think it might possibly be the sql_mode setting, which is currently STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, but I'm not sure.

Comment: now() is a function whereas 'now()' in quotes is a string, and an invalid date. I am unaware of any SQL that supports functions inside of declared strings.

Comment: I would just delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas' comment was correct. `now()` is a [function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp), and putting it inside a single quote like this, `'now()'` tells MySQL that it should be accepted as string. And assuming that the column type of the `last_modified` column is a date, then MySQL won't allow it.

Comment: I have MySQL 5.5.38 running in LAMP (different server than I am asking about) and it works fine.